# Embed component in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-components

I've tried a few different ways, but all the examples I can find for this use the template rather than templateUrl for embedding components.

At the core I have a header component that I want separate because it has the login functionality in it and displays different info depending on if you're logged in or not.  Rather than put this into the app component I figured it would be better to break it out into it's own component.  Essentially what's happening now is it builds find, but doesn't go past the `Loading...`

Even though it doesn't error out I'm assuming it doesn't know what to do with the `<header-component></header-component`

I tried a couple different syntax options for that, but all result in the same thing.  I feel like what I'm missing is somehow passing in the imported component.  I'm just not sure how.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { HeaderComponent } from './header/Header.Component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div id="header">Header</div> /*temporary place holder */
<header-component></header-component>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

header.component.html (Not currently finished.  when done will hold login functionality)

```
<ul id="links">
    <li>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/census">Census</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

header.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }



}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { routing } from "./app.routing";

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { EncounterComponent } from './encounter/encounter.component';
import { CensusComponent } from './census/census.component';
import { PracticeComponent } from './practice/practice.component';
import { LocationComponent } from './location/location.component';
import { CensusManagementComponent } from './census-management/census-management.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    EncounterComponent,
    CensusComponent,
    PracticeComponent,
    LocationComponent,
    CensusManagementComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    UserComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    HeaderComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Have your added HeaderComponent to your app declaration ?

Comment: There should be some errors in your console

Comment: @Milad   That's the weird thing, I get no errors.

Comment: @Milad I've updated the question to include the app.module.ts

Comment: I suspect that's something to do with your template url in header component or your AppModule. Could you please post your `HeaderComponent` code as well? And also, make sure that `HeaderComponent` is in your App Module > declarations section.

Comment: I added all my components using the angular cli

Comment: @Chybie I updated the question with the other .ts files.  Maybe I'll make a new app with just a single component and try embedding it just to see if it's a problem with this particular app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your header component selector is `app-header` but you use it as `<header-componet></header-component>` in HTML.

HTML tag name should always same as as `selector` name. In your `app.component.html`, change to

```
<div id="header">Header</div> /*temporary place holder */
<app-header></app-header>
```

Comment: That was it.  I figured it was a syntax issue like that. Many thanks, I should have known that.